# Why does my bootstrap-powered app website look so ugly in MSIE 8-

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

My website is http://everythingfunny.net

If you look at it in almost any browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Android Browser, etc) it looks the way i'd like for it to. I was at my parent's house, and they use IE8, and boy does the site look like a train wreck. How can I make my site more IE compatable. This is why I hate front-end development so much. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The bad news is, it doesn't look a whole lot better in IE9, and it errors in IE7...

Comment: Btw your web-page is missing it's `<html>` (root) element? Did you write the HTML code yourself?

Comment: Somehow I mostly have a different sense of humor...

Answer (score 6):

Your web-page doesn't have a doctype. As a result, quirks mode is triggered in IE.

Add this at the beginning of your web-page:

```
<!doctype html>
```

---

As for the page being off-center in IE7, this is caused by this CSS code:

```
.row {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Remove the `zoom` declaration, and the page will be correctly centered in IE7.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem for IE 8-10, IE 7 still looks weird but not as bad (its just off center), and is having the same problem in IE 6. Haven't tested in anything lower seeing most people have 6+